# What does "chrome" mean in Android Navigation?

Tags: android, navigation

If you look at the Android navigation documentation, the word **`chorme`** appears frequently.

I would like to know exactly what it means.

##### [NavHostFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment)

> NavHostFragment is intended to be used as the content area within a layout resource defining your app's `chrome` around it.

##### NavigationUI

> Class which hooks up elements typically in the `chrome` of your application such as global navigation patterns like a navigation drawer or bottom nav bar with your NavController.

Maybe duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071905/what-does-chrome-mean). But I want to clarify the definition of chrome in Android.

Comment: From the same question that you've linked: `A chrome is a replicable part of a layout or a design that surrounds a piece of content.`

Comment: @DarShan Personally, the expression "replicable part" doesn't seem to make sense to me. But I think I've found an explanation that makes more sense. https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/73488

Anyway, thanks for your comment!